# Advantages of using cmd.exe /c over not using cmd at all

Tags: c#, command-line, process, cmd

If I'm running a process in C#. Is there any benefit to using cmd /c over just running the process directly?

Ex:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
info.Arguments = "/c application.exe";
Process.Start(info);
```

as opposed to

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("application.exe");
Process.Start(info);
```

Comment: Do you know what the /c parameter does?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Yes. Hence why I'm asking the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `cmd /c`, you can execute multiple commands at once by separating the commands with `&&`. For example: `cmd /c "application1.exe&&application2.exe"`. Otherwise if there is only one process to execute, there is no difference to simply executing the process directly.

EDIT: Apparently `cmd /c` can also return an error if the process does not exist, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If we redirect the output of "application.exe", will cmd /c wait until the EndOfStream is reached? Or will it just close as soon as the process has started?

Comment: `cmd /c` is a synchronous call and will not return until the executed process runs to completion. Redirecting the output of "application.exe" would have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Another benefit of using `CMD.EXE` is if you want to execute a built-in command. Many commands in `CMD.EXE` are not separate executables but are wholly implemented within `CMD.EXE` such as `dir`, `copy`, `mkdir`, `cd`, and so forth. `MKLINK` is a built in command I've seen trip people up.

I don't know of a easy built in way to get a list of builtin commands. But you can get a list of `CMD.EXE` commands using `HELP` (which is not builtin!) and pass each command to `WHERE`. If not found by `WHERE` then the command must be builtin.

Also if you want to execute BAT/CMD files, CMD.EXE is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `cmd /c` and `cmd /k`:

It is like saying `cmd /?`:

- With `cmd /c` then executes commands series - the kernel ends.
- With `cmd /k` then executes commands series - the kernel is on.
  If you need that kernel is close, you must use `cmd /c`.
  Otherwise only `cmd /k`.

Do not forget to get out of D.O.S. IO OS with the command: exit, exit, exit, until the windows is closed.