# Executing command in ProcessBuilder does not seem to work for "java" commands in Windows (Kotlin)

Tags: java, windows, kotlin, processbuilder

Currently trying to execute a .jar file programmatically. But to test out java, I tried running the the following:

```
val p = ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "java", "-version").start()
val results: List<String> = p.inputStream.bufferedReader().readLines()
assertThat("Results should contain java version: ", results, hasItem(containsString("java version")))
```

However, nothing seems to output.

I am successfully able to run:

```
val pb = ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "echo", "hello world")
```

I have tried adding a working directory where the java executable is located, but nothing happens.
I am running out of ideas on how to make this work. If I run cmd and type out `java -version` I get the version information.

What else could I do to get this to work?

Comment: If you leave `/c` out?

Comment: Have you tried running `java` directly? (I don't know Windows, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911561/advantages-of-using-cmd-exe-c-over-not-using-cmd-at-all) seems to suggest you don't need `cmd.exe` if you're running a single command that's not a built-in.)

Comment: @jmizv I have tried removing the `/c`, however the process ends up just hanging. Not sure how to ended after that.  

@gidds I should have put this into my description, but I did try running:
`val pb = ProcessBuilder("java", "-version")`
And nothing appears in the out put when I run it

Comment: maybe it's related to the fact that `java -version` output is in stderr, not stdout

Comment: Yes, I would also check if there is something in the StdErr.

Answer (score 2):

`ProcessBuilder` writes the result of command `java -version` to error output `Process.errorStream`, not `Process.inputStream`.

Try this code:

```
val results: List<String> = p.errorStream.bufferedReader().readLines()
```

Also you may try **[Koproc](https://github.com/kochetkov-ma/koproc)** lib

It's a small Kotlin lib to run process and execute commands based on `Java ProcessBuilder`

You may run `java` process with `timeout = 120` sec :

```kotlin
val koproc = "java -jar some.jar".startProcess { timeoutSec = 120 }

koproc.use {
    println("Out: ${it.readAvailableOut}")
    println("Err: ${it.readAvailableErrOut}")
}

println("Full result after closing: ${koproc.result}")
```

Run `cmd` command:

```kotlin
// 'cmd.exe' process will be closed after timeout
val commandResult = "cmd.exe dirs".startCommand { timeoutSec = 1 }

// But you will get the output
println("Out: ${commandResult.out}")
```

See examples in unit tests: https://github.com/kochetkov-ma/koproc/blob/main/src/test/kotlin/ru/iopump/koproc/ExtensionKtIT.kt